# AWS Cloudwatch cron expressions every hour

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to set my service to be triggered hourly, based on the AWS doc:https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html#CronExpressions

Is `cron(0 * * * ? *)` the right way to define it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if it's a simple expression like hourly execution, why don't you use `rate expression`?

you set the code below in your cloudformation, serverless template or etc for every one hour.

```
rate(1 hour)
```

Comment: Because I have other schedules which are all using cron expressions, so for the consistency I want to use crom expression for this one as well. Is `cron(0 * * * ? *)`  correct?

Comment: Actually you're right, I should use the simpler one - `rate(1 hour)` is perfect, thanks.

Comment: I came across a similar one and I used `rate: cron(01 0-23/1 ? * SUN-SAT *)` that runs at the first minute of every hour (lambda is in utc). so for running every first minute in IST (ie., utc+5:30), I had to schedule using `rate: cron(31 0-23/1 ? * SUN-SAT *)`